# p:datatable loses sort column and order after ajax refresh

Tags: ajax, sorting, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a button on a page that causes my data table to refresh via an AJAX request.  Something like this:

```
<h:form id="datatable">
<p:dataTable/>
</h:form>
<p:commandButton update=":datatable">
```

This is all fine an dandy except that when the table is refreshed it reverts to not sorting anything while still showing that it's sorting based on the previous value.  In other words, the header is still highlighted and the arrow is still pointing in the sort direction but no sort is actually being performed. Obviously this isn't ideal.

Ideally I'd like the component to keep it's sort order in the view state and then submit the proper parameters during the AJAX request (so that the sort is correctly defined).  Am I missing a parameter or something?  Does anyone else have this issue?

From what I can tell when the table is expecting a sort back it posts the following options:

```
<componentID>_sortDir
<componentID>_sortKey
<componentID>_sorting
<componentID>_updateBody
```

When I refresh the form this doesn't happen.  It also doesn't happen if I just refresh the table (thought I could work around things by updating the component directly).  Is there a way to get the table to refresh correctly?

Answer (score 10):

I wrote an extension to @truemmer's solution. His reverts the sorting order back to the default, where as mine will reverts to the previous sort the user selected.

```
function postAjaxSortTable(datatable)
{
    var selectedColumn = datatable.jq.find('.ui-state-active');
    if(selectedColumn.length <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    var sortorder = "ASCENDING";
    if(selectedColumn.find('.ui-icon-triangle-1-s').length > 0)
    {
        sortorder = "DESCENDING";
    }
    datatable.sort(selectedColumn, sortorder);
}
```

Updating the same table as truemmer's works like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="refresh" action="#{tableController.refreshPrices}" update="myTable" oncomplete="postAjaxSortTable(myTableWidget)" />
```

EDIT: Primefaces 4.0 MultiSort support

```
function postAjaxSortTable(datatable) {
    var selectedColumn = undefined;

    // multisort support
    if(datatable && datatable.cfg.multiSort) {
        if(datatable.sortMeta.length > 0) {
            var lastSort = datatable.sortMeta[datatable.sortMeta.length-1];
            selectedColumn = $(document.getElementById(lastSort.col));
        }
    } else {
        selectedColumn = datatable.jq.find('.ui-state-active');
    }

    // no sorting selected -> quit
    if(!selectedColumn || selectedColumn.length <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    var sortorder = selectedColumn.data('sortorder')||"DESCENDING";
    datatable.sort(selectedColumn, sortorder, datatable.cfg.multiSort);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I'll upgrade to 3.5 soon and give it a try :) There's been lots of refactoring for tables in the current release.

Comment: I should note that I have been using this in 3.4.2. I don't know if this works very well or not in 3.5.*, but I doubt I'll be upgrading yet.

Comment: Still works under PrimeFaces 4.0 but I'm trying to improve it in order to manage multisort

Comment: Haven't found a way to perform an "datatable.sort(List selectedColumns, List sortOrders)" yet if someone finds it I will be so thankful.

Comment: @AlvaroCachoperro, this problem should have been fixed in 3.5.8 & 4.0. see http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3887. Is it not?

Comment: @srbs As Far I've understood there are many ways to fix that behaviour, the current article it's an evidence of that, but all solutions fix the one column sort problem. But my problem it´s slightly different cos I want to restore the sorted multicolumn order, I mean different selected columns in a datatable, with different orders each one. Maybe there is a solution, but can be my lack of skill makes me not see or appreciatte a solution than fix that.
Anyway thank you for your interest.
PD: Sorry for the long answer.

Comment: @AlvaroCachoperro, I just edited for multisort support

Comment: @srbs how would you call the jquery function after every time the page has been refreshed? (and not by pressing an explicit button)?

Comment: @user3601872, call the function from an onload script. try in `<h:body onload="" />` otherwise, create a new question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is an open ticket on the [PrimeFaces Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3887), which targets this question but was recently labeled as "won't fix".

Nevertheless, I found a nice workaround. The sorting of PrimeFaces tables can be triggered by calling an undocumented JavaScript method on the datatable's widget. The following might not work for future releases of PrimeFaces, but it does for 3.4.2:

Just add the following to your component, which triggers the update:

```
oncomplete="myTableWidget.sort($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('sortColumnId')}')), 'ASCENDING')"
```

The table might look like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable"
             widgetVar="myTableWidget"
             value="#{myArticles}"
             var="article"
             sortBy="#{article.price}"
             sortOrder="ASCENDING">
    ...

    <p:column id="price" sortBy="#{article.price}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Price" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{article.price}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

So updating the table could work like this.

```
<p:commandButton value="refresh" action="#{tableController.refreshPrices}" update="myTable" oncomplete="myTableWidget.sort($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('price')}')), 'ASCENDING')" />
```

Comment: In PF6.1 sortorder must be a number: 1 / -1 for 'ASCENDING' / 'DESCENDING'.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

Solution posted below (LazyTable) works for the p:dataTable backed with LazyDataModel. Overriden **load** method is called after every update/refresh on the desired table and it handles sort properly. The problem with simple p:dataTable is that it performs predefined sort only on the first load, or after the click on sort column. This is a normal behaviour of a simple table.

So what are your possibilities for simple table :

- Don't sort the table after update, but remove the sort column so end user is not missinformed. Add this to your action listener or action method for your update button :

  ```
  UIComponent table  = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":dataTablesForm:dataTableId");
  table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
  ```
- Update the sort of the table manually by script. This is not the best solution, but primefaces doesn't provide any client side function for "resorting" the table. 
  Basically you know that only one column at a time can be sorted and this column has a .ui-state-active. You can use it in a script and trigger 2 clicks on that column (1. click - other sort order, 2. click - back to current sort order).

  ```
   <h:form id="mainForm">  
  <div id="tableDiv">
     <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="item" value="#{testBean.dummyItems}">
        .
        .
        .
     </p:dataTable> 
     <p:commandButton value="Refresh" oncomplete="refreshSort();" update=":mainForm:dataTable"/>
   </div>
  ```

  And script function :

  ```
  function refreshSort(){
  jQuery('#tableDiv').find('.ui-state-active').trigger('click');
  jQuery('#tableDiv').find('.ui-state-active').trigger('click');
  }
  ```

I know this is not the best workaround, but it works. You can use it as an inspiration to make something better.

#### LazyTable

IMHO the most proper way is to update directly the component you want. So for example :

```
<h:form id="dataTableForm">
  <p:dataTable id="dataTableToUpdate">
    .
    .
    .
  </p:dataTable>
  <p:commandButton value="Refresh" update=":dataTableForm:dataTableToUpdate" />
</h:form>
```

It should work fine in this scenario (I suppose it is your purpose) : 
Open the .xhtml with your p:dataTable, sort some column (keep the facelet opened), update dataTables data from another .xhtml for example, click on refresh button. The dataTable should show your added value in correct (previously chosen) sort order - sorting was performed after update.

Hope it helped !

Comment: So the sort is maintained for you?  Or is the sort button just highlighted but the actual sort is the sort order of the objects in memory?  I tried updating the DT directly and that had no effect on the behaviour for me.

Comment: Sort button is highlighted and the sort is done correctly. Objects are sorted differently than in memory - depending on the actual sort order. I've tried it for the posted scenario and it is working completely fine for me. What scope do you use for the dataTable bean ?

Comment: I have edited the answer, let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Well the lazy table option doesn't appear to work for me. If I update the table the sort is reset. I'll have to test the other option but I suppose it would work. What does removing the sortyby do?

Comment: I used your jQuery solution and it works great. The only changes I made are:
function refreshSort(selector){
    jQuery(selector).find('.ui-state-active.ui-sortable-column').trigger('click');
    jQuery(selector).find('.ui-state-active.ui-sortable-column').trigger('click');
    }
and in the dataTable:
<p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="refreshSort('#tableDiv');" />

Comment: @jedrus07 Glad it helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

Add this PhaseListener to your application and both sorting and filtering will be kept after updating the DataTable.

```
public class DataTableUpdatePhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        if (!facesContext.isPostback()) {
            return;
        }

        PartialViewContext partialViewContext = facesContext.getPartialViewContext();
        if (partialViewContext != null) {
            Collection<String> renderIds = partialViewContext.getRenderIds();

            for (String renderId : renderIds) {
                UIComponent component = facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent(renderId);
                if (component instanceof DataTable) {
                    DataTable table = (DataTable) component;
                    if (!table.isLazy()) {
                        updateDataTable(table);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    private void updateDataTable(DataTable table) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (facesContext == null || table == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reapply filtering
        if (!table.getFilters().isEmpty()) {
            FilterFeature filterFeature = new FilterFeature();
            filterFeature.decode(facesContext, table);
        } else {
            table.setFilteredValue(null);
        }

        // Reapply sorting
        ValueExpression tableSortByVE = table.getValueExpression("sortBy");
        if (tableSortByVE != null) {
            String tableSortByExpression = tableSortByVE.getExpressionString();

            // Loop on children, that are the columns, to find the one whose order must be applied.
            for (UIComponent child : table.getChildren()) {
                Column column = (Column) child;
                ValueExpression columnSortByVe = column.getValueExpression("sortBy");
                if (columnSortByVe != null) {
                    String columnSortByExpression = columnSortByVe.getExpressionString();

                    if (tableSortByExpression != null && tableSortByExpression.equals(columnSortByExpression)) {
                        // Now sort table content
                        SortFeature sortFeature = new SortFeature();
                        sortFeature.sort(facesContext, table, tableSortByVE,
                                SortOrder.valueOf(table.getSortOrder().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)),
                                table.getSortFunction());

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is for non-lazy data tables. Data tables using a lazy model do not require this, as the lazy model will take care of sorting and filtering. For non-lazy data tables, this should work with both single and multiple column sorting but there is a bug in Primefaces that makes DataTable loose its MultiSortMeta between postbacks when updating the table. This means that the columns selected for sorting before postback are completely lost from FacesContext and component state and cannot be retrieved anymore upon postback. I'll look more into this later and provide an update if I manage to find a workaround or maybe Primefaces will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I implement a Comparator with my toString() method

```
municipios = municipioFacade.findAll();
Collections.sort(municipios, new DefaultComparator());
UIComponent table = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":municipios:municipios-tabla");
    table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
```

**comparator**

```
public class DefaultComparator implements Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a conversational bean. In this case the p:dataTable refreshes the table and its entries without affecting the sort order. In the case when you have a p:commandButton on each line the table refresh works correctly too.

The conversational bean:

```
@Named
@Stateful
@ConversationScoped
public class ItemBean {

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    private List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    public void retrieve() {
        // if it's an Ajax call then avoid retrieving items
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            return;
        }
        // start a conversation
        if (this.conversation.isTransient()) {
            this.conversation.begin();
        }
        this.items = retrieveItems();
    }
}
```

The associated page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{itemBean.retrieve}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="table" var="_item" value="#{testBean.items}">
    ... <!-- you can have the p:commandButton in a column too, to refresh the respective column only
        <p:commandButton value="Refresh" action="#{itemBean.update(_item)}" 
        -->
    </p:dataTable> 
    <p:commandButton value="Refresh" action="#{itemBean.update}" update=":form:table"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I was able to fix the issue using a [LazyDataModel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf). Because of the [PrimeFaces issue with the row index](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1544), I needed to add the extra UtilitiesLazyDataModel(see row index comments):

```
public abstract class UtilitiesLazyDataModel <T> extends LazyDataModel<T>{

    public UtilitiesLazyDataModel() {
    }    

    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        /*
         * The following is in ancestor (LazyDataModel):
         * this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
         */
        if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
            super.setRowIndex(-1);
        } else {
            super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
        }      
    }
}
```

Then use your `LazyDataModel` class with this:

```
public class MyDataModel extends UtilitiesLazyDataModel<MyObjectClass>{

//override getRowData and getRowKey

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rares Oltean's approach could also be implemented using preRenderView event listener.
On your jsf page register listener:

```
<f:event listener="#{managedBean.preRenderViewListener}" type="preRenderView" />
```

and implement it in a ManagedBean:

```
public void preRenderViewListener() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (!facesContext.isPostback()) {
        return;
    }

    PartialViewContext partialViewContext = facesContext.getPartialViewContext();
    if (partialViewContext != null) {
        Collection<String> renderIds = partialViewContext.getRenderIds();

        for (String renderId : renderIds) {
            UIComponent component = facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent(renderId);
            if (component instanceof DataTable) {
                DataTable table = (DataTable) component;
                if (!table.isLazy()) {
                    updateDataTable(table);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void updateDataTable(DataTable table) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (facesContext == null || table == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!table.getFilters().isEmpty()) {
        FilterFeature filterFeature = new FilterFeature();
        filterFeature.decode(facesContext, table);
    } else {
        table.setFilteredValue(null);
    }
    ValueExpression tableSortByVE = table.getValueExpression("sortBy");
    if (tableSortByVE != null) {
        String tableSortByExpression = tableSortByVE.getExpressionString();
        for (UIComponent child : table.getChildren()) {
            Column column = (Column) child;
            ValueExpression columnSortByVe = column.getValueExpression("sortBy");
            if (columnSortByVe != null) {
                String columnSortByExpression = columnSortByVe.getExpressionString();
                if (tableSortByExpression != null && tableSortByExpression.equals(columnSortByExpression)) {
                    SortFeature sortFeature = new SortFeature();
                    sortFeature.sort(facesContext, table, tableSortByVE, table.getVar(),
                            SortOrder.valueOf(table.getSortOrder().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)),
                            table.getSortFunction());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not using prime faces, I faced similar issue of restoring the column sort once the page data gets refreshed. My page was getting refreshed with new data every minute and I did not wanted the user to click on column to sort every time.

Setting stateSave: true only did not work in chrome browser. So I had to use stateSaveCallback and stateLoadCallback methods along with stateSave: true. Please refer to below link for further details.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave