# Assign 'value expression' in place of 'method expression' in JSF

Tags: jsf, action, el, commandbutton

In my composite component, I iterate a `list<list<javaDetailClass>>`. I get all my `<h:commandButon>` attribute's values through value expression like `#{iterator.value}`. But the problem comes with attribute `action`, where action accepts only `method expression`. whereas I can assign only value expression there, resulting in `MethodNotFoundException`

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="formElements" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.formElements}" var="element">
        <c:forEach items="#{element}" var="iterator">

                <h:commandButton id="#{iterator.id}" 
                value="#{iterator.value}"

                action="#{iterator.action}">

                </h:commandButton>
        </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
</cc:implementation>
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

this will be the detail class in my situation,

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

public class TestData {

/*Properties based on the implementation of your composite.
Change type where it is needed*/
private String id; 
private String value; 
private String attributeName; 
private String action; 

public TestData() {
}

/*Getters and setters omitted*/


}
```

Bean.java simply holds an ArrayList of ArrayList. The constructor simply created five TestData objects and assigns some default value to its attributes.

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.*; 

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

private ArrayList<ArrayList<TestData>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<TestData>>(); 

public Bean() {
    ArrayList<TestData> testDataList = new ArrayList<TestData>(); 
    TestData data; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        data = new TestData(); 
        data.setId("ID" + i);
        data.setValue("VALUE" + i);
        data.setAttributeName("ATTRIBUTE" + i);
        /**this sets the action attribute of TestData with a API from some other managed bean**/
        data.setAction("someOtherManagedbean.someactionAPI");
        testDataList.add(data);
    }

    list.add(testDataList); 
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<TestData>> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<ArrayList<TestData>> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

}

index.html simply calls the composite by assinging the value of "#{bean.list} to the name attribute

Comment: try action="#{iterator.action.toString}"

Comment: @zargarf: Thanks for ur comment...but it's not working

Comment: @zargarf: please try yourself before posting potential nonsense.

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190467/custom-elresolver-to-handle-method-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `TestData.java` has the following method `public String getAction()` (since I'm seeing a `setAction(String)`) and not 
`public String action()`. Therefore, the reason why you are getting a `MethodNotFoundException` is because you are supplying the wrong method name to the `action` attribute. In your case it should be `iterator.getAction` and not `iterator.action`. You only supply the abbreviated names when an attribute is expecting a value expression.  The interface below has been modifed.

```
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="formElements" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.formElements}" var="element">
            <c:forEach items="#{element}" var="iterator">
                <h:commandButton id="#{iterator.id}" 
                                 value="#{iterator.value}"

                                 action="#{iterator.getAction}">
                </h:commandButton>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </cc:implementation>
```