# How to change primefaces databtable sort icons

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have a tab view , inside the each tab view I have a data table.

this is my code snippet:

```
<p:tabView orientation="left" id="myTabs" activeIndex="#{myBean.currentTabIndex}" dynamic="true" cache="false">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" immediate="true" update="@form" listener="#{myBean.onTabChange}" />
            <p:tab id="vehicleTab"
                <ui:include src="/components/vehicle.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
        ----------- other tabs --------------
    </p:tabView>
```

And vehicles.xhtml is :

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable"  var="v" value="#{myBean.vehicles}"   rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{myBean.sort}" />
        <p:column id="vehicleid" sortBy="#{myBean.object}"  sortFunction="#{myBean.sortVehicles}">
            <h:outputText value="v.id" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column id="type" sortBy="#{myBean.object}" sortFunction="#{myBean.sortVehicles}">
            <h:outputText value="v.typ" />
        </p:column>
        //other columns
    <p:dataTable
```

If you observe, **sortBy**  attribute has same for all the columns, **v.object**
this v.object has sorting related metadata to sort.

When I clicked on the column, sorting is working fine, sort icons are showing correctly. But, if I navigate to another tab and back to the vehicle tab sorting is there but all icons are showing same either desc or asc previous sort icons.

When I debug the code, I observed that,the datatable renderer' class decode method is invoked if I click on column for sorting;

> @Override
>       public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
>       }

Inside this method

> DataTableFeature

class has decode method it's taking the sorting column, sorting function from context parameters which are provided by framework.

After this method execution completed then

> @Override
>       public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException{}

this method is invoked and sorting icons are prepared.

But when I switch the tab and back, the **decode** method is not getting invoked directly **encodeEnd** method is invoked, preparing sorting icons same for all columns.

This was the earlier implementation, is there any way to solve this issue without changing the **sortBy** attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to this:  [p:datatable loses sort column and order after ajax refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032356/pdatatable-loses-sort-column-and-order-after-ajax-refresh)

Because a tabView change if you are using real TabView are actually AJAX requests every time you change the tab.